# backBarbuttonitem does nothing?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have set the navigation programmatically

in a view controller I set a backbutton and only change the title as per documentation.
however clicking on the back button in the child controller does nothing.

what did I miss?

```
> in a viewController

    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = ""
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a target and action to the button,

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = ""
backItem.target = self
backItem.action = #selector(back)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

and then implement the back() function.

```
func back() {
    // If your view controller was presented by a navigation controller
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    // If your view controller was presented modally
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Actually both work for swipe gesture.  dismiss is dismissViewControllerAnimated(animated: true, completion: nil), but not .touchUpinside of the backButton. Is this behaviour normal? how can i add the TouchUpInside ?